# How to load text file into a String variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I've been trying to load a text file into a variable, so that I can check if the user's input is valid. However, I've been having difficulty trying to store the output of the `rootBundle.loadString` function into a useable String variable, and I'm not sure how to do it.

My code:

```
Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
  return rootBundle.loadString(path);
}

String text = getFileData("assets/textfile.txt");
```

How would I store the contents of a text file in a variable as a string type?

Comment: Can you tell me what issues you're facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

You need to await the [loadString](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/loadString.html) method, it's return type is `Future<String>`.

```
Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
}

String text = await getFileData("assets/textfile.txt");
```

Comment: When assigning to a String, it says: `A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.`. How would I use the output of this function?

Comment: Please check this official dart documentation for async programming. @12rhombiingridwnocorners https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await

Comment: sorry if my questions are stupid, but how would you store the Future value as a string instead of printing it?

Comment: See that link and check ```Example: asynchronous functions```, there ```var order = await fetchUserOrder();```. Here fetchUserOrder() is Future<String> method. Just read that whole article, surely you'll get to know about it.

Comment: Ohh, I think I see what my problem was. I need to parse through the contents of the file in an async function, right?